# symfony and doctrine: two fields pointing to one entity

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine

I'm have a problem figuring this out. I have two entities, user and country. Within user, i have two field, country_of_residence and nationality. I would like both these field to point to country::id like so:

Conception tables:
[image: Conception tables]

Is this possible to do in symfony-doctrine? And how can it be done? ManytoMany relastionship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `ManyToOne` relationships

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_of_residence", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $countryOfResidence;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nationality", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $nationality;
```

Comment: After doing that and updating the entities, i get the error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`nugd_staging_twixlove`.`#sql-57ae_4461a`, CO  
  NSTRAINT `FK_B1087D9E8AC58B70` FOREIGN KEY (`nationality`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`))

Comment: All i had to do was to clear the tables. Thx for your help.